# How can I create a linux .sh scipt to replace all periods between numbers, with hyphens between numbers, in all filenames recursively

Tags: bash, recursion, replace, filenames

I am trying to create a bash script to find and replace all filenames containing n.n with n-n recursively from a certain directory. My filenames might contain several periods but I only need to change the periods between numbers.

I want to replace these filenames as I created a lot of them by mistake. My media player lists filenames correctly when dashes are used instead of periods. I am a total newbie in this subject so my attempt at a script will be a long way off the mark.

I have searched and found several posts regarding changing filenames, but none specific to my needs and I am unable to get my script to work via trial and error!

The filenames I want to replace are much alike these and in many sub-directories.

```
1.1.4 Mr. Ben goes home.mp4
01.03 How do I do This.mp4
2.4 Please help.wav
1.2 3.4 foo.bar
```

which I want to change to:

```
1-1-4 Mr. Ben goes home.mp4
01-03 How do I do This.mp4
2-4 Please help.wav
1-2 3.4 foo.bar
```

I asked a very similar question and got a few tips, but this was before I joined and I can't seem to continue with that. I apologize for asking twice!

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.*; do
    mv "${file}" "${file//\d\.\d,\d\-\d}"
done

read -n 1 -p "Hit any key to exit"; exit
```

Comment: Please take a look at [how to format my code block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Are '.mp4' and '.wav' files the only ones that need to be renamed, or are there others (e.g. '.mkv')?

Comment: What would be the new name of this: '1.2 3.4 foo.bar 5.6.wav' (note the space between the '2' and the '3')?

Comment: I need to replace mainly .mp4 files, but there may well be mkv, m2ts, ts and flv files.   Mp3 and wav files are generally unique, unlike unknown video titles for a series, hence the numbered filenames.   1.2 3.4 foo.bar 5.6.wav should ideally have only the number of the file up to the first space, so would become 1-2 3.4 foo.bar 5.6.wav.   My names are nearly always going to be like:   01.01 foo.ts   01.02 bar.ts   1.3 foo bar.baz.ts   But some will be like: 001.02.01 foo.ts 001.02.03 bar.ts Etc. Any '.' not between two numbers at the start of the name should remain.   Eg. 1.2.1 foo v1.4.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Perl's `rename`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730894/what-about-rename-different-versions-and-usage-what-is-the-recommended-way-to/730895#730895):

##### Input files:

```
$ ls -1
'1.2 3.4 foo.bar'
'2.1 Please help.wav'
'2.4.5 Please help.wav'
'2.4 Please help.wav'
```

##### Code:

```
$ shopt -s globstar # enable recursion **
$ rename -n 's/(\d+)\.(\d+)(?:\.(\d+))?/join "-", @{^CAPTURE}/e' ./dir/**/*.*
```

Remove the `-n` switch when the output looks good enough. (test mode)

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `(` | group and capture to \1: |
| `\d+` | digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `)` | end of \1 |
| `\.` | . |
| `(` | group and capture to \2: |
| `\d+` | digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `)` | end of \2 |
| `(?:` | group, but do not capture (optional (matching the most amount possible)): |
| `\.` | . |
| `(` | group and capture to \3: |
| `\d+` | digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `)` | end of \3 |
| `)?` | end of grouping |

##### Output:

```
$ ls -1
'1-2 3.4 foo.bar'
'2-1 Please help.wav'
'2-4-5 Please help.wav'
'2-4 Please help.wav'
```

Comment: I have now installed perl's rename and it works a treat on num.num files, but I am unable to make it work with filenames like num.num.num foo.mp4

Comment: `num`s are digits or is string as-is? If string, edit your post to add this case

Comment: I've just realised, this works great when ran for a second time which will replace a 2nd number period number sequence (if it exists) Great...

Comment: Post edited accordingly, works in one shot

Comment: Post edited, removed the `g` modifier. That fits the new requirement to not replace when you have `num.num` after a space